# QuestaSim/ModelSim simulation gives me unkown value in wave window. However I get them as X and x, what is the difference between the two?

Tags: digital-logic, simulation, modelsim

What is the difference between big X and small x when we get red (unknown) signals in QuestaSim? I would assume it to be the same in ModelSim simulation as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IEEE Std 1364-1995 § 14.1.1.4 "Unknown and high impedance values" and 
[IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 21.2.1.4 "Unknown and high-impedance values":

> - If all bits in a group are at the unknown value, a lowercase x is displayed for that digit.
> - If all bits in a group are at a high-impedance state, a lowercase z is printed for that digit.
> - If some, but not all, bits in a group are unknown, an uppercase X is displayed for that digit.
> - If some, but not all, bits in a group are at a high-impedance state, then an uppercase Z is displayed for that digit, unless there are also
>     some bits at the unknown value, in which case an uppercase X is
>     displayed for that digit.

Example:
`8'b1111_xxxx` => displays as `8'hFx`
`8'b00x0_1001` => displays as `8'hX9`
`8'b1010_zzzz` => displays as `8'hAz`
`8'b0z00_0110` => displays as `8'hZ6`
`8'b0zx0_1010` => displays as `8'hXA` (unknown has higher display priority over high impedance)

Answer (score 1):

Are you viewing a signal in hex radix? IIRC big 'X' means all the bits of your radix are unknown, while little x means that some but not all of the bits are unknown.

Maybe something like:

```
4'hX = 4'bxxxx;
4'hx = 4'b000x;
```

I don't know if this the standard on all simulators, but you could check to confirm by looking at the binary radix.